# Does favorite question notification work?

Tags: support, faq-proposed, bookmarks

Is the feature of notifying the user about any changes to a favorite question implemented or not? If it is, I've noticed that it doesn't work, since I don't receive any notifications on favorite questions.

Also, maybe we should have a FAQ about this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They don't deliver to your inbox, but they do show up here:  https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/580/slybloty?tab=favorites

Comment: I know they show up there, but I was inquiring about notifications on changes.

Comment: @slybloty -- I asked in the mods forum, and they don't notify

Answer (score 2):

We've punted on favorites notifications for a while now:

> [Adding Favorites to the Stack Exchange global inbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83343/adding-favorites-to-the-stack-exchange-global-inbox)

We're thinking of a simple rss feed until we can revamp what favorites should actually be - simple bookmarks or "notify me as if I own this question".

Comment: I like the notification idea.